# Como funciona while(scanf("%c", &c) == 1)

Tags: c

Cuando inicio el programa, el scanf queda en el loop de while; como puedo condicionarlo para que solamente la palabra en una array solamente una vez
para despues detectar el numero de vocales, y consonantes?

```
char palabras[20]={0};
        char c;
        
        while(scanf("%c", &c) == 1)
    {
        palabras[c-'0']++;
    }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

repasemos las bases del while loop:

```c
int x = 1
while (x) { // X es 1 y es compilado como true
  /* Código aquí */
} // se repetirá hasta que x no sea 1
```

ahora las de scanf:

```c
int scanf(restrict char *format, ...);
/* Devuelve un int, toma un puntero a 
   caracter y va_args (generalmente 
   direcciones de memoria de puntero) */
// por ejemplo:

char x;
scanf("%c", &x);
/* Indicamos que queremos escanear un carácter
   y le pasamos la dirección de memoria donde la vamos a guardar */
```

la documentación de scanf indica que el int de retorno es la cantidad de coincidencias con el formato, es decir si le indicas capturar un carácter como en tu caso devolverá 1 siempre ya que tomara los números en su valor de carácter 
Entonces:

```c
char c;

while(scanf("%c", &c) == 1) { // Al escanear un carácter devolverá 1 
  /* lógica de tu programa */ // Ejecutara el codigo
} // pero no saldrá de aquí
```